# Advice on 20 sensors and their max length cable on one ESP board

Tags: voltage, sensor, esp32, cables, proximity-sensor

I would like to add about 20 inductive proximity sensors to Home Assistant using an `ESP32-S3` board. 1 sensor per window (open/close) and 2 per door (open/close & lock state). I've got my proof of concept working with ESPHome and am able to get them nice and flush in the door frame. On to the next step and the main question.

I was thinking of using CAT cable to connect the sensors to the board. So for a door with two sensors I would use 1 pair for power, 1 pair for GND, 1 pair for sensor wire open/close and 1 pair for sensor wire lock state.

Parameters:

- Sensor is rated for 5 V

  - Using 5 V results voltage drop from 4.5 V to 0 V on detection(as per design)
  - Using 3.3 V results voltage peak from 2,74 V to 2,82 V on detection
- I would us between the 15 m (50 ft) and 25 m (80 ft) for one sensor(group).
- Board is rated 3.3 V GPIO in

Questions:

- Is is advisable NOT to use these lengths of wire for sensors?

  - What would be the problem with this
- Would choosing between 3.3 V or 5 V option effect the length question/answer?

  - (If I go for 5 V I could optocouple the signal for the GPIO in)
- I was initially considering powering it though a USB charger with 3.3 V OR 5 V from the board pins. Would this suffice?

Note:

- Come to think of it while writing. I don't think the ESP32-S3 had this many ADC pins :)

Comment: Can you give a datasheet for the sensors? They're probably open drain output but would like to confirm.

Comment: I'm unable to find an "official" datasheet. Seems to be generic. Type is `LJ12A3-4-Z/BX `. Strange Now it seems 6/36V, I'm pretty sure I double checked the 5V. I've bought 2 other 6/36V versions before that did not work. Anyway, I'm open to part suggestions. Since I need one with a smaller footprint. This one is M12 And I need max M8 in diameter.

Comment: https://datasheetspdf.com/mobile/1096182/ETT/LJ12A3-4-Z/1 
http://www.control-electrical.com/Catalogue/Inductive_Proximity_Sensor_LJ12A3-397.html Give some more info.

Comment: It's an open collector output so you can choose the output high level with a pullup resistor. Why do you mention ADC pins in the question? It's a digital signal.

Comment: Alright. Since I need new parts I can also buy a NC instead of the NO sensor. The ADC came from the sensor on 3.3 V. I was able to read the raw voltage change on closing the lock. It did not switch HIGH / LOW. I guess since it's not rated for 3V it gave a side effect.

Comment: Well it's specified for 6V supply so it's not surprising it doesn't work on 3V supply.

Comment: :) I bought the with the description in the shop of 5V. So 3V readout was already a surprise. Anyway I'll go search for 5V sensors. Question remains, can I run 2 sensors per cable of 20m? I would expect a voltage drop. I'm now thinking of just cutting a CAT cable to the longest length and measure the voltage drop with the or a new sensor. And just see if a readout is possible.

Comment: i doubt voltage drop will be a problem.